# What happens under the hood when you specify more partitions than the number of cores available?

Tags: apache-spark

For example, my laptop has 8 cores and if I submit:

`sc.parallelize(1 to 100, 30).count`

Does it execute 8 tasks first then the other 22 tasks is executed one by one when a core becomes available?

Is there a way to verify what happens under the hood myself via the SparkUI or logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it execute 8 tasks first then the other 22 tasks is executed one by one when a core becomes available?

Yes. Spark UI has an event timeline view to observe it [1]. You can also see when a task started in the Spark logs.

[1] https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html

Comment: The link was very useful! Follow up question: If the number of tasks can never be higher than the number of cores, then there's no reason/benefit to ever assign more partitions than number of cores, correct?

Comment: Totally depends on the data, e.g., bad partitioning,  data skews, stragglers (slow nodes). I would consider using more partitions than the number of cores if your partitions are large and the overhead of scheduling tasks is pretty low.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last response (due to my limited knowledge). I created another question for this. Could you answer it there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284477/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-run-more-partitions-than-number-of-cores