# Does it ever make sense to run more partitions than number of cores?

Tags: apache-spark

Does it ever make sense to run more partitions than number of cores given that the number of Spark tasks cannot be higher than the number of cores? If so, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As you mentioned you need to have at least 1 task / core to make use of all cluster's resources.
- Depending on processing type required on each stage/task you may have processing/data skew - that can be somehow alleviated by making partitions smaller / more partitions so you have a better utilization of the cluster (e.g. while an executor runs a longer task that takes 5 minutes other executors are able to run 10 shorter tasks of 30 seconds).
- There might be other scenarios where you want to increase the number of partitions (e.g. if you hit size / memory limitations).

  Check out this nice article about parallelism tuning: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

**Update:**
How this can help with processing/data skew and give you a better cluster utilization and faster job execution (an example screenshot below from Spark UI where you can see the skew between tasks - see diff Median vs Max task duration):

Let's say you have a cluster that can run 2 tasks in parallel.

- Processing the data takes 60 minutes with 1 task (1 idle core) - job takes 60m.
- If you split it in 2 you may find because of the skew: Task1: 45m, Task-2: 15m. Job takes 45m (for 30m you had 1 idle core).
- If you split it in 4 you may get: Task1: 30m, Task-2: 10m, Task-3: 10m, Task-4: 10m. Job takes 30m (1st core runs 1 task for 30m while the other runs the other 3 smaller tasks of 10m each). 
  etc.

[image: Skew: Max vs Median]

Comment: Just to make sure I understanding the point about data skew: if I have a partition with a bigger dataset than other partitions, it would be more efficient to break that up into smaller partitions so other Executors and Tasks can process it in parallel as opposed to waiting for the big partition to processed by one Task. Did I understand you correctly?